# Is it possible to do linear interpolation for a function of more than one variable in R?

Tags: r, interpolation, spatial-interpolation, multivariate-partition

In practice I need an extension of the approx function that already exist in R to the multivariate case. Something similar to the interp function in matlab but coded in R on in C.

Hope somebody can help me!

Comment: Try `akima`, `fields` packages.

Comment: I need to interpolate a function of 5 variables, akima works for the bivariate case only. Do you know which function I should look at in the package fields? Thanks!